# MySQL query to return multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, outer-join

I want to write a MySQL query that will:

1. Hash the primary key
2. Hash all the columns (including the primary key)
3. Return two columns (pt1 and pt2)
4. Order by Asc pt1 (primary key)

Here's my query, I get an error saying result consisted of more than one row

```
SELECT SHA2(CONCAT(id), 256), SHA2(CONCAT(cola, colb), 256) INTO @v1, @v2
FROM mytable
ORDER BY @v1
```

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause to specify *which* row you want to hash.

Comment: or add `LIMIT 1` if only one the top one. The thing is you can only put one row `INTO` the variables

Comment: the hashing is already done by SHA2 in the Select

Comment: SELECT ... INTO can manages only one row...

Comment: Again the error is clear. Your select return more than one row. So you either restrict the `SELECT` with `WHERE` or `LIMIT`, or remove the `INTO`. Tell us what you need so we can orient you better

Comment: You're right. I removed the INTO param and put 1 in Order By to sort it by the first column. It's working fine now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Was there a question somewhere? "*Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. ... It features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming.*"  You might notice that no one has yet offered an answer. Maybe that's because there wasn't a question. I'm just offering some comments. (But thanks for offering your evaluation of what I "need to" do.) https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/